# Temporizador em C#

Tags: c#

Estou programando a tela de um game onde vai mostrar a pontuação do player em modo progressivo, ele mostra a pontuação ao final da partida porém não mostra com o efeito de tempo entre os números. meu while está errado?

```
int n = 0;
while (n < sPontuação) 
{
    n++;
}
Console.WriteLine("", n);
```

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa função então não tinha como eu procurar por ela! Como posso alterar a pergunta?

Comment: Alterar por quê?

Comment: foi marcada como pergunta duplicada e recebi aviso para edita-la de modo diferente. sou novo aqui no forum..

Comment: voce vai manter minha pergunta como duplicada?

Comment: Sim. Ela é duplicada. Não é?

Comment: Sim, porque o que você pediu já está solucionado na outra pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. Acho que vai de ponto de vista, pois essa existente não resolveria minha duvida, sou novato em c# e para mim apenas o while bastava..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu while está correto, porém para dar esse efeito de contagem faltou utilizar o método System.Threading; que é um timer para execução em milissegundos.

faça essa modificação no while:

```
int n = 0;
while (n < sPontuação) 
{
    n++;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
}
Console.WriteLine("", n);
```

Comment: foi isso mesmo muito obrigado